# how to get alert if mouse moves out of inner window in y axis

Tags: javascript, jquery

how to get  alert if mouse moves out of inner window in y axis. In present condition iam geting alert in both x-axis and y-axis . ie if mouse pointer move on address bar from body.

```
 $(function(){

    $(document,window,'html').mouseleave(function(){alert(1)})
    });
```

**example**:
http://ezwebsitebiz.com/testing-content/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check the axis like this:

```
$(function(){

    $(document).mouseleave(function(e){

       if( e.clientY < 0 ) {

            console.log('Mouse left Y axis');  

       }

    });

});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8g5zyuru/

Comment: `e.clientY < 0 || e.clientY > window.innerHeight` http://jsfiddle.net/8g5zyuru/1/

Comment: in the provided example it checks only top part